# Function does not take one arguments

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum_average(int a,int b,int c, float & avg);

void input (int& , int& , int& ); 

void display(int sum, float avg);


int main()


{
    int sum;

    float avg;

    int a, b, c;

    input(a,b,c);

    sum= sum_average(avg );

    display(sum , avg); 

    cin.ignore();

    return 0;




}

void input(int&a , int & b, int &c)

{


cout << "enter the value:";

    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    cin.ignore();

    return;

}


int sum_average( float & avg)

{

    int a, b, c;

    int sum = 0;


     input(a,b,c);

     sum = a + b + c;

    avg = (float)sum / 3;

    cin.ignore();

    return sum;

}

void display(int sum, float avg)

{
    cout << "the sum =" << sum << endl;

    cout << "the avg =" << avg << endl;

    cin.ignore(); 

    return;
}
```

Comment: The `sum_average` declaration has four parameters. You are passing it one argument.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you were a compiler and you see:

```
int sum_average(int a,int b,int c, float & avg);
```

You'll tell yourself "I'm expecting a function called `sum_average` that takes 4 arguments".

Now a programmer comes and write `sum_average(avg)`. This will break your heart.

You should *forward declare* your function like this:

```
int sum_average(float& avg);
```

Now the compiler will know what is `sum_average`.

Comment: the imput function calls 2 times but i want it one time... what can i do...

Comment: Remove one of the calls.  You call it in `main` and `sum_average`, pick one.

Comment: +1 for anthropomorphized compilers with feelings.